# Logstash output : Tags on stdout

Tags: output, logstash

As a newbie in ELK, i'm doing many tests to get used to this environment.
I would like to print the tags generated by Logstash in the the CLI, but I didn't find how.

Is it possible ? I don't want to send it to elasticsearch and then look for the data with Kibana, I just want to know if the tags are here and which ones.

Here is a sample of what i'm trying to do : 
I'm using http_poller to get data from a list of URLs, and i'd like to see if the correct HTTPcode is given

```
input {
    http_poller {
        urls => {
            "url1" => "https://www.google.com"
            #"url2" => "https://www.facebook.com"
            #"url3" => "https://www.amazon.com"
            #"url4" => "http://www.google.com"
            #"url5" => "http://www.facebook.com"
            #"url6" => "http://www.amazon.com"
        }
    automatic_retries => 0
    #Check les URL toutes les 30sec
    interval => 30
    #Considere la requete en Timeout au bout de 8secondes
    request_timeout => 8
    tags => website_healthcheck
    }
}
filter{
    if [http_poller_metada][code] == 200{
            mutate{
                    add_tag => "Good request"
            }
    }
}
output {
#Debug
if "Good request" in [tags]{
    stdout{
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Right now the output is unreadable (google's html page), I'd like to read only the HttpCode.

Sorry for the poor explanation, and thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to replace the `message` field with the tag field, so you will only have the httpCode in your output.

```
mutate {
  replace => { "message" => "%{[http_poller_metada][code]}" }
}
```